# ArcGIS REST Fails in OpenLayers TileArcGISRest - Works on Desktop

Tags: openlayers, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to load ArcGIS REST map into OpenLayers and having trouble.

The demo from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-tiled.html works great and I've modified it to try other URLs and basic stuf from arcgisonline works fine for that.  I've included my modified `main.js` and `index.html` below.

The issue is changing to this URL:
https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer

The service seems to up and down a lot, but even when working, I get a black/white checkerboard instead of details when zooming into a city block.  It does load using the "[ArcGIS Online Map Viewer](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/mapviewer/index.html?url=https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer&source=sd)" and on my desktop QGIS, but I can't get it into OpenLayers.

Is this ArcGIS REST different, and how do I handle it?

main.js

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {OSM, TileArcGISRest} from 'ol/source.js';

var url = '';
//url = 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA/MapServer';
//url = 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer'
url = 'https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer';

const layers = [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  }),
  new TileLayer(
{    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new TileArcGISRest({
      url: url,
    }),
  }),
];
const map = new Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [-9041148, 4489099],
    zoom: 10,
  }),
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tiled ArcGIS MapServer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ol/ol.css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileArcGISRest-TileArcGISRest.html) of `TileArcGISRest` tile source you'll see this description:

> Layer source for tile data from ArcGIS Rest services. Map and Image
> Services are supported.
>
> For cached ArcGIS services, better performance is available using the
> XYZ data source.

Looks like there is performance problem with this service, since tiles are generated on the fly when using `TileArcGISRest` tile source. Here is an example of such a tile request:

> https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer/export?F=image&FORMAT=PNG32&TRANSPARENT=true&SIZE=293%2C293&BBOX=-9001224.450862356%2C4578883.742395198%2C-8962088.692380344%2C4618019.500877208&BBOXSR=3857&IMAGESR=3857&DPI=103

Alternative is to use cached tile source. You can find all the necessary info for constructing XYZ tile source with the right tile grid at https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServery.

Code for this tile layer could then look something like this (tested):

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}?blankTile=false',
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
      origin: [-9325754.0, 4989694.0],
      extent: [-9294707.135673312, 4498859.250759878, -8556631.190551685, 4922014.639346593],
      tileSize: 256,
      resolutions: [611.4962262813797, 305.74811314055756, 152.87405657041106, 76.43702828507324, 38.21851414253662, 19.10925707126831, 9.554628535634155, 4.77731426794937, 2.388657133974685, 1.1943285668550503, 0.5971642835598172, 0.29858214164761665, 0.14929107082380833, 0.07464553541190416, ]   
    })
  })
})
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And here is an example of high zoom:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't too familiar with tileGrid so this will help me a lot now and down the road!